# Why is this server program not able to send anything to the client?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

I am basically trying to make a chatting app but here I am unable to send anything from the server to the client. How do I correct this?
server program:

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7777
s=socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print "Server is Ready!"
while True:
    c, addr= s.accept()
    print c
    print addr
    while True:
        print c.recv(1024)
        s.sendto("Received",addr)
s.close()
```

client program:

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7777
s=socket()
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    s.send(( raw_input()))
    prin s.recv(1024)

s.close()
```

It is giving me error at `s.sendto` in server program saying:

```
File "rserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.sendto("Received",addr)
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Comment: Did you try to use a socket return'd by accept? Change s.sendto("Received", addr) into c.send("Received").

Comment: doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the connection socket to send or receive objects so the problem is there only....

Use -

```
c.sendto("Received", addr)
```

instead of

```
s.sendto("received", addr)
```

Second problem is you are not receiving the messages from the socket... Here is the working code

server.py -

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7777
s=socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print "Server is Ready!"
while True:
    c, addr= s.accept()
    print c
    print addr
    while True:
        print c.recv(1024)
        #using the client socket and make sure its inside the loop
        c.sendto("Received", addr)    
s.close()
```

client.py

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7777
s=socket()
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    s.send(( raw_input()))
    #receive the data
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
         print data
s.close()
```

Comment: File "rserver.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.send("Received")
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied